# How can I calculate the Time Remaining on the current otpcode?

Tags: swift, time, passwords

I'm producing an otp every 30 seconds using the algorithm to generate otp code, but now I want to get the remaining 30 seconds of it, how much time this otp has to expire from those 30 seconds. Thank you for helping me

Comment: After generating one otp, start a timer for 30 seconds and take one member variable i.e timeRemaining set it to 30 initially, then in the timer callback function you can decrease timeRemaining value till zero and can check the time remaining value.